# How can I dynamically populate a CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, checkedlistbox

I want to populate a CheckedListBox based on the items passed into a form's constructor (in this case, a List`<int`>).

My skeleton code for this is:

```
foreach (int platypus in listPlatypi)
{
    userFriendlyPlatypusName = ExpandFromPlatypusID(platypus);
    // I want to store a verbose string in an Item of the CheckedListBox, something like:
    // Item item = new Item(userFriendlyPlatypusName); // what data type should "Item" be?
     CheckedListBox1.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Were you looking for [`checkedListBox1.Items.Add(userFriendlyPlatypusName);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z38x31c0(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: oh, boy - why that wasn't obvious to me yesterday is now mind-boggling and embarrassing.

Comment: Don't be embarrassed: I made the EXACT same just 5 minutes ago. Thanks @ keyr for the answer and you for the question.

Answer (score 5):

The answer depends on what you are doing outside of the skeleton code listed.  What matters is what information your code needs when acting on the list items later.

`CheckedListBox` works just like `ListBox`.  The text displayed is the result of each item's `.ToString()`.

If strings work, then add the display name text.

If you need more information stored per Item, add a `ToString()` override to your class and `.Add()` the full item.

If that's not an option, create a small display wrapper:

```
public class PlatypusDisplayWrapper {
   public Platypus {get; set;}
   public override string ToString() { 
       return this.Platypus.Name;
   }
}
```